# Why does the appended text's font family change in an editable div?

Tags: html, css, contenteditable, font-family

```css
* {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.sample {
  font-family: monospace !important;
}

.sample>* {
  font-family: monospace !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="sample" contenteditable>
  This is not inside span. <span>Go to the next line and append some text to see inconsistent effects.</span>
</div>
```

Playing around doing more editing only exposes more inconsistencies. How to fix it? How to set `monospace` font to all the text inside the `div`? I tried removing `!important`, but to no avail.

Removing `<span>` is an option, but I can't do that in the original project I'm working on because those elements have certain formatting. Neither can I remove the `*` rule declaration, because I want `sans-serif` font outside of the div. Quite annoyingly, both solve the problem. Any other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`>` selects immediate children. When you create a new line, you'll notice that the `span` tags are wrapped in a `div`.

Instead, you can try selecting all `span` elements that are children of `.sample`:

```css
* {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.sample {
  font-family: monospace !important;
}

.sample span {
  font-family: monospace !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="sample" contenteditable>
  This is not inside span. <span>Go to the next line and append some text to see inconsistent effects.</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that, by defining `.sample>*` the font will only be applied to the immediate child, excluding all others. If you check the result of jumping to a new line and writing something, you will see that it creates a new div and a new span layer, that's why your CSS is not applied. If you simply change `.sample>*` to `.sample *` it will work as expected.

```css
* {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.sample {
  font-family: monospace !important;
}

.sample * {
  font-family: monospace !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="sample" contenteditable>
  This is not inside span. <span>Go to the next line and append some text to see inconsistent effects.</span>
</div>
```